# how to order by <= 7 desc then by > 7 asc?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, sql-order-by

in my table https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/0

i use query

```
SELECT id
FROM test
ORDER BY id <= 7 DESC, id DESC
```

i want to order everything from 7 to lesser by the bigger then everything else by the lesser

my query give me

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 6   |
| 3   |
| 2   |
| 1   |
| 65  |
| 35  |
| 34  |
| 33  |
| 12  |
| 11  |
| 11  |
| 10  |
```

but i want to give me

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 6   |
| 3   |
| 2   |
| 1   |
| 10  |
| 11  |
| 11  |
| 12  |
| 33  |
| 34  |
| 35  |
| 65  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a conditional sort, like so:

```
select id
from test
order by
    case when id <= 7 then id end desc,
    id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d70c53868aae1802217a4993bce82e11)**:

```
| id |
| -: |
|  6 |
|  3 |
|  2 |
|  1 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 11 |
| 12 |
| 33 |
| 34 |
| 35 |
| 65 |
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT id
FROM test
ORDER BY id <= 7 DESC, 
         (CASE WHEN id <= 7 THEN id END) DESC,
         id ASC
```